# Some Tailwind CSS styles are not being applied

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Some Tailwind styles are not being applied.

[image]

In this image, you can see that two classes are added to this div, but these styles are not available in the DOM.

Help please.

Comment: The `pb-6` (`padding-bottom: 6px`) class should be in the linked tailwind CSS file. Are you sure your linked to it correctly? Which version of tailwind are you using? Post your `<head>` DOM content (including all `<link>` tags).

Answer (score 0):

I can see two possibilities: you're building classes dynamically in Javascript (hard to say without seeing your code), or you did not recompile your Tailwind classes.